# Annotate with Count yields incorrect values with NullBooleanField

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I am performing the following query with a few annotations:

```
    (AwardIssueProcess.objects.filter(grant__client=client, completed=completed_status)
        .annotate(total_awarded=Sum('award__awardissuedactivity__units_awarded'),
                  num_accepted=Count(Case(When(award__accepted=True, then=1))),
                  num_rejected=Count(Case(When(award__accepted=False, then=1))),
                  num_unaccepted=Count(Case(When(award__accepted=None, then=1)))))
```

However, the `num_unaccepted` yields incorrect values. Firstly, if I have awards the number is sometimes double what I expect. But if I remove

```
total_awarded=Sum('award__awardissuedactivity__units_awarded')
```

from the annotation, then the doubling problem goes away.

Secondly, the `num_unaccepted` has a value of 1 if there are no awards. But when there are awards, the value is correct (but not is all cases due to the doubling problem I mentioned previously). In this second issue, I suspect that this may be because it is evaluating the award to be `None`, but what I really want is for it to check if the `accepted` field is `None`. And then if the award doesn't exists, just don't count it. The `accepted` field is a `NullBooleanField`.

How should I be writing this differently to solve these two problems with `num_unaccepted`?

**EDIT**

I removed `total_awarded=Sum('award__awardissuedactivity__units_awarded')` from the annotation and created a separate function to get the `total_awarded` amount that I need. This addresses my first problem, but the second issue still remains.

Comment: That is the expected behavior: if you `JOIN` on two independent tables, you "multiply" the rows. So if there are two `awardissuedactivity` elements, then every `award` row will be doubled.

Comment: I see, thanks! However, the `num_unaccepted` being 1 is still an issue when there are no awards.

Comment: Well in that case there is probably for that `AwardIssueProcess` item either no or one `awardissuedactivity`.

Comment: I updated and removed any reference to `awardissuedactivity` in the annotate (see my edited question). So how can it still be an issue?